# Which() not matching given row to row of dataframe

Tags: r

I want to match a one-row data.frame to another data.frame. The values in the one_row data.frame are definitely present in the other data frame. I wanted to use the function which(), to get the index of the row at which it matches but it is not working. (see the code below)

[image]

```
x  y
4  53


x   y
13  69
97 122
4  53
33 154

idx= which(medoids==a, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

> ```
> Error in Ops.data.frame(medoids, a) : 
>   ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
> ```

But i expect :idx= 3

Answer (score 2):

You could use [interaction](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/interaction) inside which to join the two columns and allow a comparison.

```
medoids <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "x  y
4  53")

a <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "x   y
13  69
97 122
4  53
33 154")


idx <- which(interaction(medoids)==interaction(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data frames are not the same size, you need to use `mapply` in order to map the columns one-by-one and compare, i.e.

```
mapply(function(x, y)which(x == y), medoids, a)
#x y 
#3 3
```

**NOTE:** You do not need `arr.ind` since you are comparing 1 dimensional vectors (individual columns)